# [META] Voting Etiquette

Tags: meta, voting

### Under what circumstances do you vote a *question* up or down?

Let's have a little discussion on voting and friendly behavior.

Asking and answering questions is not the only way to participate on BrewAdvice. The thing that differentiates this site from a forum is the way good questions and answers sift their way to the top.  Voting makes this possible.

Answer (score 7):

1. Any time I give an answer, I **upvote** the *question* <sup>†</sup>
2. Commonly asked questions (like recurring forum questions) get my **upvote**
3. If I think the question is relevant, clear and *concise*, I **upvote** it
4. When the question is irrelevant or general, I **downvote** it
5. I am *more likely* to **upvote** a question from *new registered* users
6. I am *less likely* to **upvote** a question from *unregistered* posters

† Except in cases where I am prohibited to upvote, like my own questions

Comment: I follow the same guidelines.

Comment: I like to see questions with at least as many votes as answers.

Comment: I know I'd like to see more voting happening.  There are two many questions with many views and 0 votes.  I nee dto be more dilegent about this too.  I like Deans general guidelines.  I don't have a feel yet for how I have been voting.

Comment: Hey Dean, In your example guidlines do you ever NOT vote? And Why?

Comment: Chez: Since the site it new I vote liberally. The cases I don't vote usually fail #3 because they aren't relevant *to me*.  EG: the threads on chocolate extract and corking beer.

Comment: Re: Down voting, definitely leave a comment when you down vote something. -- http://brewadvice.com/questions/663/meta-down-voting

Answer (score 0):

When I think an answer is good or is similar to the answer I was planning on giving I upvote it (and I now add a comment [since I got that ability] to expand on the answer if I feel it's necessary/useful).

Comment: I'm asking about voting on questions, not answers.

Comment: Doh! I guess you should also thoroughly read a question before you answer or vote for it.

Comment: And now we see the answer voting system in action! (-:  You can always add another (more appropriate) answer to a question.

Comment: You can also delete an answer, if you don't think it should be around on the site. "Cleanup", if you will.

Comment: Though, I'd leave this one as a example :)

Comment: Glad to be of service?